# Make total of formula match a value by changing one value in formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a formula:

```
((a+i)*p)+b=total
```

The formula already has values and a total, but I need the total to match a new total. I can only do this by changing i.

This is needed for a piece of software.

How might I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 2**:
Let's suppose that $\rm{total}$ is increased by $d\,$ to give $\,\rm{total}'=\rm{total}+d\;$ then you go from $$\tag{1}(a+i)\cdot p+b=\rm{total}\;$$ to $$\tag{2}(a+i')\cdot p
+b=\rm{total'}\;$$ 
(we search $i'$ in function of $i$ and the other parameters)

Subtracting $(1)$ to $(2)\,$ gives :
$$(a+i')\cdot p+b-(a+i)\cdot p-b=\rm{total}'-\rm{total}$$
$$a\cdot p+i'\cdot p+b-a\cdot p-i\cdot p-b=d$$
$$a\cdot p-a\cdot p+b-b+i'\cdot p-i\cdot p=d$$
$$\tag{3}(i'-i)\cdot p=d\;$$
or dividing by $p$ :  $$\tag{4}i'-i=\frac dp\;$$
You may conclude that if $\rm{total}$ is replaced by $\rm{total}'=\rm{total}+d\,$
then you only need to replace $i\,$ by $$i'=i+\frac dp=i+\frac {\rm{total}'-\rm{total}}p$$

Hoping this clarified things,

Comment: I think +l-i could be expressed as +l and l could be a negative or positive figure. That should make things simpler.

Comment: Yes of course @MarkW (I updated my answer).

Comment: im sorry. I dont understand the equations. Its the strange characters that throw me. I'm not a good mathematician.

Comment: @MarkW: I added more details and replaced $\Delta$ by $d$ (I hope it will be less confusing).